# Post facebook without the access token in python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to be specific. I have an app created in facebook When logged manually (go in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) I get access token type:

`"CAAVLIUVx7w0BAPRY9h6IfBKmolxumLLGbvwpLzLh7YG5gWrSOqczbqJM31AnZAW86RPrudLpJ123TKYqZBZCGxR8R1JvBNUQZBCSG2EMXuliaqrgiJKZd213CZA0gQ0c6NdmsJA1mUSrSjxEVLcsZA4OXK8X1hlV9ioWtp20mp81cQJ6YKivh2Jrwt1ZBmffo1YQKUWW6o2WViEuEpQ5suQZDZD"`

Then I introduce the access token code in python and works perfectly, but when I close the session on facebook this access token stops working and gives me the error:

`OAuthError:` `[190] Error validating access token: This May be Because the user logged out or May be due to a system error.`

**My question is: Is there any way to get the access token automatically without human intervention.**

*(sorry, I speak Spanish and I am using a translator)*

Thank you for responding friends.

Comment: Depends on the type of access token – to get a user access token, user interaction is required. The lifetime of user and page access tokens can be extended though, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: then it is definitely not possible to create Python script that automatically post time ? = ' (

Comment: Depends on where you want to post, and what type of access token you want (or need) to use for that.